# Creating an android layout of image buttons that is scrollable?

Tags: android, listview, button, layout, scrollview

I am stuck trying to create a layout of image buttons similar to the picture provided that is vertically scrollable. [Desired Android layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9HPD.png). I am using **android studio**. The app crashes if I add any more image buttons than 12 (which is only enough to fill one screen).
I would like to be able to have a number of image buttons in rows of 3 that can be scrolled down through. I have tried using `ScrollView` & `ListView` but have had no luck. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: What is the size of each image? What kind of exception you've got?

Comment: use a RecyclerView with custom Adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a grid view.
For reference 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Include `GridView` in your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Refer that GridLayout in your java class and set adapter to it.

```
 GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

Adapter Class to inflate Views to your GridLayout.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
}
```

Comment: While links may answer the question but t's not advised to post them alone as answers. In future, if the link gets modified, the answer will be of no use. Instead add the relevant solution form the link in the answer, and provide link as a reference.

Comment: The link is from android.developer site.. which gets regular updates from google itself. As well, i have included a sample code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Asymmetric Gridview,

```
<com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.widget.AsymmetricGridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

For more see [Asymmetric Gridview](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView)